# Is 30 years long enough to remove all evidence of the United States of America?

Tags: time

In my story which is taking place in 2050, there is no United States of America. The only reference to the USA is an old military bunker where the characters are currently hiding. Is 30 years long enough for all references to the USA to be removed?

This just means like the presidential seal, paperwork, online sites and references, etc. All the buildings are still there, but there is no online reference. places like the white house and the senate building are also still around, just repurposed for the new leaders.

The timeline for the stories background-

2020: reference removal starts

2020-2030: filled with plagues, world population falls to 3.5 billion

2030-2050: reference removal continues

EDIT- i only mean removing references in the USA.

EDIT2- someone seems to think I need more details, so I'll add in some more.

online references are destroyed first by hackers. after that, people come in disguised as doctors and stuff to start destroying all the hard copies of stuff referencing the USA. mount rushmore becomes just some rich guy's sculpture he made, and american currency starts losing its value. after a bit, all the old people are dead and they start collecting all cash, trading it out for virtual currency kinda like bitcoin but its standard currency. now american currency is just fire starter and play money.

once the government is taken over, the government buildings hold the new leaders, or become auditoriums(mainly court houses) or mansions(governors houses)

Comment: 30 years later the people remembering the US are still alive. 70 would be better.

Comment: No, its not nearly enough to seek out and burn all copies of Jules Verne's [*Nord contre Sud*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texar's_Revenge,_or,_North_Against_South) (1887). Not to mention the countless other novels, history books, documentaries, photos, TV series, etc. etc. floating around in this great world. Do you have any idea of how many copies of Alexis de Tocqueville's [*De la démocratie en Amérique*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_in_America) exist in how many languages in how many libraries?

Comment: I think there is  hundred thousands of "MAGA" hats in New York souvenir shops that while produced in China have U.S.A written on tab with USA flag.

Comment: I think that especially after major world collapses, removing these references wouldn't be practical. If you mean world-wide, your America haters will need to rule the whole planet, and every random book or movie with a casual USA reference, every useful thing that says "MADE IS THE USA" would raise questions.

Comment: If you want people who don't know about the USA, the only plausible way is to shelter them from information itself, rather than destroy all information everywhere. Make some sort of gated community and restrict access to information they can access. Books, internet, other people, etc. That way, you can have them ignorant of something. Otherwise, you cannot really do it.

Comment: Who's going around organizing this massive iconoclasm in the midst of the apocalypse? Shouldn't they be doing something more important like farming or doctoring or making sure they have an ammo supply chain?

Comment: how many of those 4 billion deads are americans?

Comment: @RodolfoPenteado, half of whatever the current usa population is now died from the plagues.

Comment: Are these things being purposefully destroyed or just normal decay? how powerful is the organization doing the destroying? can they go to the moon? you need to clarify this question, it is too vague right now.

Comment: @John, purposefully.

Comment: Don't forget that GitHub archived many many repositories in Norway. The storage medium is supposed to last for 1000 years and there is undoubtedly references to the USA in some repos. Unless someone were to drop a couple of nukes over there, it wouldn't be vulnerable to hackers (I think) because the repos are stored on film

Comment: In a word: impossible. If, on the other hand, what you're asking is, "in the geographical area currently known as the continental U.S. we find a totalitarian government that won't ever let its people travel or receive communication from outside the area - is it possible for that group of people to not know the U.S. in just 30 years?" the answer is yes - so long as you kill everyone older than about 10 years old (human memory).

Comment: BTW, I did not cast a VTC, but the reason people are voting to close is that we don't understand important limits (like those mentioned in my last comment). What specific geographical area are we talking about? What technology is available (especially communication)? What are the demographics of the people in the area? Are there any interior (government) or exterior (government/activist) influences? How many people are we talking about? How much freedom to travel do they have? 30 years is a very short period of time. How did you destroy all the books, flags, art, oral history?

Comment: I'd Like to point out that your scenario forgets the items in orbit, on the moon and on Mars.  They're not going anywhere.

Comment: I'm thinking of a different question.  Is 30 years long enough for people to grow so apathetic about the USA that that no one will rise and defend it when a group of fanatics decide to rewrite all of its history in negative terms?  It almost seems as though the history from 1990 to 2020 proves it.

Comment: Do US coins count?  This is, are you asking if all coins will have to be recovered and melted down?  Because it's kinda hard to imagine all US-minted coins being located in a reasonable time-frame; so many are likely buried in all sorts of misc. locations, including deeply buried in garbage dumps and encased in concrete at the base of buildings, that locating-and-removing all of them would seem like a pretty extreme task.

Comment: Despite China's best efforts, they haven't managed to erase the Tiananmen Square Massacre from their own people's memory in 30 years. It's heavily suppressed information which you are severely punished for even mentioning, but there are still people alive who remember it and it appears in textbooks outside China.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This time is not enough even to remove all memories of the USA. There were still be about 10-30 % of people (depends on average lifespan and who is plague main target) who grew up in USA. And there would be a lot of people with memories of reference removal process.

As for physical evidence - there would be a still lot of writings and things that would not be destroyed. Like car plates in litter, old newspapers in attics and so on. USA produced (or imported) too many "patriotic" staff to found it all.

All this "american things" would be a rare find if it is penalized to own or not reporting them. But the penalty itself would be the greatest reference to the USA

P.S. I am talking about USA territory only, not the whole world.

P.P.S Destroying information about smth is like winining The Game (you lost! ha-ha - I know it is stupid). It is possible only on several generations timespan. And still archeologists would discover some references in distant future.

Comment: For example, [William Manchester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Manchester) [*The Death of a President*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_a_President) is a bigggg (as in, 700 pages) book, translated in many languages, and very popular in many countries in the late 1960s and early 1970s. It is simply an awful lot of paper to seek out and burn.

Comment: I remember the warszaw pact and I was 10 when the SU broke apart. I will continue to remember it until I die. 30%? No, lots more I guess.

Comment: @Anderas, there were an plague and old men are die first in such apocaliptic conditions.

Comment: *Attack on Titan* brought up a similar issue. One of the plot points that something suspicious was going on is that *nobody* remembered what life was like before the walls, and it was pointed out that at least some of the current adult generation should have heard *something* from their grandparents, even if it was only in hushed tones behind closed doors. 100 years is short enough for one generation of word-of-mouth rememberance.

Comment: We still remember Rome after 2000 years, and can even recreate the Proto Indo European culture that is almost 5000 years in the past, despite a comppete lack of written records and very few artifacts. We can even go back 20,0000 years to our Ancestors at the start of the "cognitive revolution" - the United States will be a visible presence in history and culture for centuries, if not millenia in the future.

Answer (score 14):

I know the Anglo-Saxon kingdom of Mercia existed, over a  thousand years after it ended. It is not just that my personal library includes one of many copies of a translation of the Anglo-Saxon chronicle. Coin collections include coins issued by kings of Mercia. The Oxford English Dictionary defines "mercian" as "A native or inhabitant of the Anglo-Saxon kingdom of Mercia, in central England" and "The Anglian dialect of Old English spoken in Mercia". Spenser's "Faerie Queene" includes a reference to "warlike Mertians". A Google search for Mercia returned about 5,780,000 results.

A thousand years is not long enough to erase all evidence of a small and not particularly prominent country. I suspect there will be at least as much evidence for the existence of the US a thousand years after its demise, even if there were some effort to erase the evidence.

Comment: Even the Khwarezmid empire is still remembered to the present day, even if the context of that rememberance is "this is what happened to people who pissed off Genghis Khan". Big empires, especially ones that were historically significant in some fashion, would be really difficult to delete from history and would leave a very noticeable hole. E.g., "who was the Cold War between", "who fought in World War II (especially in the Pacific)", "what happened to the British colonies in North America", and so on.

Comment: This is my preferred answer. Frankly, *thousands* of years isn't enough. There's a lot of evidence of Rome (2,000 years), ancient Egypt (5,000 years), and physical evidence of other civs that go back [10,000 years](https://www.oldest.org/culture/civilizations/). It would take a long, long, long, long, long time to erase all evidence of the U.S. - or any current nation, frankly, although the smaller the nation the easier it would be. They'd be lost in the archeological "noise" of what other nations leave behind.

Comment: Erasing a literate nation surrounded by, and interacting with, other literate societies is especially difficult.

Comment: I generally agree with the conclusion, absolutely, but this says nothing about how many smaller nations we don't know about.  For example, we know that there were Peoples in Germania that the Romans called Saxons, Franks, Lombards etc. but those names were actually not the nations that existed there.  The Romans used these names to describe barbarian groups by what weapons they used, but there are no surviving records about the actual names, territories, and cultures of the Celtic nations of Ancient Germania; so, there are also holes that have been so filled in we often don't even notice them.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: The "Celtic" nations of ancient Germania? What "Celtic" nations of ancient Germania? And the Romans never called anybody "Franks" or "Saxons". Those are not Latin words, and the Franks and Saxons emerge on the historical stage mostly after the fall of the Western Roman Empire. The Franks called themselves Franks. The Saxons called themselves Saxons. Unless you believe that the dastardly Romans somehow convinced the people of Sussex, Wessex and Essex to use those names when they came there *after the Romans had left Britain*.

Comment: @AlexP Yes, Celtic civilization originated around modern day Austria and spread across at least half of Europe including at various time frames significant portions of modern day France, Germany, Spain, Portugal, the British Isles, Hungary, Romania, Denmark, Belgium, and the Netherlands.  The word Franks get their named from the throwing ax, the Francisca, and the Saxons preferred a style of swords called the Seax or in latin, the Sachsum.  Our histories of these peoples are all written from the Roman perspective because they did not do a good job of writing their own history books.

Comment: Keep in mind that the era after the fall of Rome is called the Dark Ages for a good reason.  We don't really know very much about the actual political structures or what people called themselves in that period, so without a written history to go off of, it's possible these names were just what someone started calling someone and it stuck for lack of more information.

Comment: Let me revise that previous statement: Denmark and Northern Germany are marked on some maps as separate from the Celtic cultural zone, but inclusive of Celtic on others.  That said, most sources seem to consider them separate; so, I think I see why you questioned me calling Germania Celtic.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: Ah, *those* Celts. I was thinking in the context of your statement about the Romans. The poor Romans had no contact with *those* Celts. When the Celts were inhabiting Germania, Rome was a small town in cental Italy. And, surprinsingly, there were some little points of light during Dark Ages... For example, with reference to the Franks and the Saxons, [Gregory of Tours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_of_Tours) and [Bede the Venerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede) wrote the *History of the Franks* and *The Ecclesiastical History of the English People*.

Answer (score 10):

Do you know the novel [Nineteen Eighty-Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four) by George Orwell?

It describes a fictional attempt to destroy the public memory of their history. It is a **massive** effort by the *Ministry of Truth* to destroy historical evidence and even the language that would allow people to think seditious thoughts. Yet it takes an effort to "re-educate" the population to actively reject facts which would get them into trouble with the government.

---

The comments asked me to elaborate. It will take *nothing less* than an active suppression campaign of the evidence, and even then there will be plenty of clues to get curious minds thinking. That curiosity needs to be suppressed as well.

When I was young I talked with an old German veteran about the Holocaust. He told me that he had seen people being escorted into a forest, and the escorts coming out again. His sergeant told him *not to ask*. So he didn't ask at the time, and he couldn't *prove* they were Jews, and he couldn't *prove* they were shot. But he thought about what he had seen and after the war he talked about it.

In your setting, people like that must be stopped from talking.

Comment: +1 for Orwell. Also its a good remember on this book the little interview that Winston did with one old man about the past.

Comment: I *think* I know where you are going with this, but I think this answer would take off with a little more elaboration...

Comment: So the conclusion is... it takes active, dystopian destruction and re-education to erase the memory of something so large as a nation?

Answer (score 5):

No.  For about as close a historical parallel as I can think of, think of the ~1700 year (since Constantine, basically) effort of the Christian Church to displace & destroy previous religions.  Yet we still have references to the gods of these religions in literature and everyday speech (at least among some populations), in holidays (even if they're covered with a Christian veneer) and even in the names of the days of the week.

Answer (score 5):

Two things get nations remembered for thousands of years: Achieving a superpower status, and inventing something really important.  The US has done both of those things; so, the likelihood of wiping the US out of history in the next 3000 years would be questionable, much less the next 30:

**How the US is a Superpower**

People remember superpowers because they affect everyone else's histories, not just thier own.  The Assyrians, the Babylonians, the Persians, the Romans, the Aztecs, the Incas, etc.  Even really short lived super powers like the Huns and the Macedonians are still well remembered to this day.  While these names may not all be known to every common person, wiping out thier memories completely is all but impossible.

As a military superpower, the US has one of history's best track records of winning conflicts over any several hundred year period.  Since it was founded, the US has participated in [116 wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_the_United_States) which is unto itself a crazy figure.  But when you add to that that the US and its allies have won 98 of those wars outright, 13 ended inconclusively or mutually, and only 5 were lost... there is no doubt that history will remember America as military empire simply because there are so few places on the globe that have not been affected by US military interference.  Even if all those peoples who lost choose not to remember the US, those few peoples who won will always want to remember it.  The US lose of the Vietnam War was such an anomaly that it will probably be remembered thousands of years from now the way we remember the Persians losing the Greco-Persian Wars.  Especially if Vietnam ever goes on to become historically significant.

Even if you don't remember the military power of the US, it's status as an economic superpower is also historically significant like that of the British Empire.  At its height, the US controlled 70% of the world's wealth.  Even if this level of power was short lived in the grand scheme of things, it has impacted the history of every other nation in the world.  When people in China talk about the birth of thier industrial revolution, when people in Saudi Arabia talk about the great petroleum boom, when people in Russia talk about the collapse of the Soviet Union, it will be in reference to the American economy.

**The Importance of American Inventions**

The thing about historically important inventions is that we look incessantly to find out where they all come from.  Historians have a bad habbit or really looking under every rock and reading ever scrap and relic trying to find this piece of information; so, even obscure nations can become historically significant if they invent something important enough. Do you remember the Phoenicians? They were not a great empire, most people don't know much about them, but they invented the first phonetic alphabet 3000 years ago, so we still remember them despite thier otherwise obscure place in history.

So what did the US invent worth remembering 3000 years from now? Well there is the internet for starters.  Even if TCP/IP is not the same in a few thousand of years, as long as there is something like a computer and they form something like an internet, the US will be credited for its invention.  There is also television.  In a future where we don't use screens, there will still be holodecks or some nerolinked entertainment device and thier history "books?" will have images of TVs in remembrance of precursor tech the same way we remember abacuses and movable type printing presses as important precursor tech.  Still not good enough? How about Nukes?  It's hard to imagine there being a future where a nuke could conceivably be anything other than a powerful, world changing weapon. Then there is stealth technology which is in my opinion one of the greatest military advancements since the discovery of body armor... sure it will change a lot over time but I can't even conceive a way that future tech might progress in such a way as to render it obsolete for any significant period of time.

But maybe your future is a dark age where technology is actually in regression, well, as it turns out America has some good contributions there too. Americans invented assembly lines making mass production of complex products possible, even with limited skills and technology to draw from.  In the realm of agriculture, Americans invent mechanized farming; so, even a civilization scraping by to keep the gears of industry running will invest in not having to farm by hand.  Heck even if your world regresses to early iron age levels of tech; someone is going to remember about Compound Bows.

Comment: I'm fond of remembering [Philo Farnsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo_Farnsworth), who invented the greatest babysitting tool in history &mdash; television.

Comment: Wait a second... if Phil Fry is related to professor Farnsworth... I believe there may have been an inside joke there that I've been missing for the past 20 years.

Comment: Even supposing the world regresses to the stone age for thousands of years, if it ever advances again to the point of sending people to the Moon, there will be American artifacts waiting for them there.

Comment: Every country that has membership in, or at least representatives in, the UN, will have paperwork and records of where that was headquartered.

Answer (score 4):

Mount Rushmore is predicted to still be recognizable for several tens of thousands of years if all conservation work ceased on it, and still be recognizable as faces for millions of years afterwards. Along with the Channel Tunnel in the English Channel it is thought to be one of the last manmade objects that will exist in a recognizable form if humanity was ever to disappear. The rock Rushmore is made from is super hard and erodes really slowly. Even if the context of Rushmore is lost, those faces would still be viewable even by a post-apocalyptic civilization.

That, at the very least, is the low bar you have to clear for removing all evidence of the U.S. and its history.

EDIT: Thanks to @chasly-reinstateMonica for pointing out my mistake with terminology

Comment: Do you mean the Channel Tunnel? I don't think we Brits lay claim to actually digging the English Channel! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Channel  - On the other hand - the Suez Canal ...

Comment: In a deliberate effort to erase US references, the faces on Mount Rushmore could be destroyed by strategically placed explosives, the same way they were produced.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: No need to deface the sacred faces of the ancestors who brought to us the first grains of maize across the river of heaven... Faces on a rock pass very quickly into folklore. (My favorite is the equestrian statue of the most pagan Marcus Aurelius in Rome, which was spared during the Middle Ages because they thought it was the most Christian Constantine.)

Comment: @AlexP Good point. Given the surviving structures there would have to be a mythology of the Golden Age, and any monuments would be interpreted in that mythology.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. The only possibility I can think of is if some catastrophic event wiped out humanity (nuclear war, asteroid impact, etc.) and a select few people survived or traveled to the area. Even then, there would be a lot of artifacts, although they moght not be easy to find, especially if you set your story in an uninhabited area like rural Nevada, Idaho or the like.

Answer (score 1):

**No - The rest of the world will know and have records**

Unless you destroy every single radio in the country, citizens will still be able to receive broadcasts from all around the world. They will even be able to put together simple new radios. The skills to do this will remain for many years. Even in North Korea these days, people can illegally learn about the the rest of the world by radio. In China, I'm sure the government would like to stop people knowing much about the rest of the world (e.g. banning of Google) but they can't stop long-wave radio.

Are Canada and the South American countries still in existence in your scenario? Even without radio, information will leak across the borders.

Comment: Anyone living in a South American country will remember that there was a North America and the central namesake of that continent.

Answer (score 1):

Not accurate, but let me tell you a story of a country. It had grown into power, one of the largest countries in Europe. It was capable of fighting off its enemies for centuries, sustaining people and prolonging its existence. It had its rich culture, official language and many unofficial languages being used, its social layers and everything else that you can imagine for a country existing for so long. Yet, after 800 years of existence, changing, alliances, wars, after about two turbulent centuries with both internal weakness and strengthening enemies eventually the country was invaded by its neighbours, captured and literally ceased to exist, the land and people partitioned between the three occupants.

All the three occupants put a lot of effort to eradicate any trace of the country existence. They forbade using the language and teaching anything about the culture or history of the country. They enforced the inception of their languages, culture, way of being, government, everything. The country was supposed to disappear not only from maps, but also from the heads and hearts of its former citizens and their descendants forever. It was doomed to cease to exist.

And yet, after 123 years of the alleged non-existence, chasing an opportunity so slim that it should never work, the country not only reappeared. Two countries being direct descendants of the original one reappeared! And despite various problems, a war that once again temporarily wiped the countries from the map, years of occupation and again non-existence for one of those two new countries, and again difficult times attacking culture and identity, more than 100 years of the initial reappearance, the two countries are still on the map (even though one of them disappeared again for almost 50 years).

The initial country I am referring here is Poland, that over time became a Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth. In 1795, after the third partition, it ceased to exist. The three invaders, Russia, Prussia and Austro-Hungarian Empire tried to eradicate any trace of Poland, enforcing germanisation and russification on the captured lands. But the knowledge about Poland was running in the families, passed between the generations like a huge treasure. The people mutinied, helplessly tried to re-capture independence, looking for any opportunity to recreate its country. They tried to benefit from Napoleon wars, fought in numerous uprisings, kept underground learning, some fled the country but kept their roots and bonds to the original country, continuing its tradition and culture. And when another surprising opportunity in the form of world war came, they grasped it and at the moment of their occupants' weakness announced the independence of not just one, but two countries - Poland and Lithuania. These events brought back the countries in 1918 to the map of the world, proving that 123 years of constant education is not sufficient.

This all happened before the times of the Internet, when sharing the knowledge was far more difficult than these days. It proves that even 100 years timeframe is not enough to eliminate all traces of the country existence. It's not enough to remove all physical traces (that will probably also not be so easy). You have to eliminate it from hearts and memories.

So no, even if we experience some huge disaster tomorrow, 30 years from now the memory of the United States will be still strong.